# Printing chat messages above the prompt?

Tags: c, client, chat

For my situation, say Tim and Bob are chatting using my C chat client and server. My chat client and server is executed on a bash terminal. The cursor for this chat program is the **~** key.

Tim sends Bob a message that says, **"Hey"**. Now say that Bob receives this message as he's typing a message to Tim. Bob wants to send **"Hello"** to Tim, but he hasn't finished writing it yet (so he's only written **"Hel"** so far).

I would like my application to be able to keep Bob's prompt and his entry so far at the bottom of the terminal, and display Tim's message above the prompt. Bob should still be able to finish his message to Tim, as well as being able to see Tim's message. Below is a diagram of what I mean, from the view of Bob's client. Is there any way of accomplishing something like this using C?

........................Before............................................................................................After...............................

```
...............................                 .................................
...............................                 <Tim> Hey
Enter Message> Hel~                             Enter Message> Hel~
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to make this either a curses or an ncurses program, rather than just printing to stdout.

Comment: Short answer, yes.  But, you'll be better off linking to ncurses, it can remember cursor positions, move to new, then restore when needed.

Comment: It's not fully finished yet and has a few bugs. I was wondering more if there was an implementation that would allow me to manipulate the stdout prompt.

Comment: You can use the `\r` and `\b` escape sequences to print over already printed characters, but I am not aware of any way to back up over a newline. If using them with stdout, you may have to also use `fflush` or make it unbuffered since it is usually line buffered by default and you won't see anything until you print a newline.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. Ncurses seems to be the way to go. I didn't even know about it!

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you're using an ANSI compatible terminal AND know your prompt length AND cursor position (assuming you allow editing of input so that the cursor may not be at the end of the current input) AND don't allow more than one line of input [ a lot of assumptions there ] then it would seem you can output one or more 'cursor up' sequences then a carriage return, your message from Tim, a carriage return, a linefeed and then lots of 'cursor right' sequences to put the cursor back where it was.

Basically, though, if you want to handle this sort of complication then you're going to head to a curses/ncurses/terminfo kind of library.